# Trillium Director is not getting up in MDM.Can anyone suggest

Tags: tibco-mdm

I am from MDM Tibco team.
We are just finished with Unix security patching and now we have restarted MDM Server and we are getting Trillium issue.
Trillium Director is not getting up in MDM.Can anyone suggest.

Thanks
Shruti

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is about programming issues and your question seems to be about system administration. Have you tried to look at https://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks I will try serverfault.com